# SQL Server XML queries against text data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a `ntext` data type column which contains XML content, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
    [SampleId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [XMLContent] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SampleId] ASC
    )
)
```

Can I run XML queries against a `Ntext` column in SQL Server?

So far I can do workaround using like queries but would like a better approach.

Comment: What do you mean by XML queries, my guess the simple answer would be no if you are talking about XQUERY or other similar query languages.

Comment: like the queries against xml data types

Comment: SQL server just sees the data saved in the column as plain text. You need to parse it as XML and then query it, AFAIK.

Comment: Change the datatype of the column to XML.

Comment: @marc_s Does your comment not qualify as an answer?

Comment: @user2989408: if you would be using `XML` as your datatype - then **NO**, SQL Server isn't just storing "plain text" - it's storing the XML in a optimized, tokenized fashion and uses **less** storage than when storing just the plain XML text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. In order to use XQuery - you must be using the `XML` datatype.

If that columns really does contain only XML - what's stopping you from changing it to be `XML` (which is should be in the first place, really)?

If you can't change it (again: why not!?!), then you need to CAST(XMLContent as XML) for every single operation:

```
SELECT
    CAST(XMLContent AS XML).value('.....', '..')
```

and so forth - not a very useful and helpful approach.

Furthermore: `TEXT` and `NTEXT` are deprecated and should not be used anymore - use the more appropriate datatypes like `XML` or `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` instead

Comment: you know there are some situations where you are not the owner of the database, other thing that run-time queries require only text. so it makes sense to have it text (probably will have better performance) while some reporting queries require xml that's why casting will fit.